# Django: How to output error_message in paragraph <p> instead of list <li> format

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple form which uses a SessionWizardView to spread it over a number of pages. Below is an example of one of the questions.

```
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='What is your first name?', error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your first name'})
```

Which renders out as

```
<label for="id_0-first_name">What is your first Name?</label>
<ul class="errorlist">
    <li>Please enter your first name</li>
</ul>
<input id="id_0-first_name" maxlength="100" name="0-first_name" type="text" />
```

Can anyone tell me hwo to change the error output so that it is in `<p>` Paragraph `</p>` format rather than `<li>` List item `</li>` format?

I am using Django 1.6.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as @schillingt suggested and create your own error list class.

Or, if you want to handle this in your template, you can use something like:

```
<form method="post" action="/some-view/">
    ... other fields, etc. omitted ...

    <!-- The label and form field -->
    {{ form.first_name.label_tag }}
    {{ form.first_name }}

    <!-- Output any errors -->
    {% for error in form.first_name.errors %}
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    ... other fields, etc. omitted ...

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

#### Update

In order to do this in a cleanly repeatable way, make a template named `form-field.html`:

```
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}

    <!-- Output any errors -->
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Then, update your main template:

```
<form method="post" action="/some-view/">
    ... other fields, etc. omitted ...

    {% with field=form.first_name %}
        {% include "form-field.html" %}
    {% endwith %}

    ... other fields, etc. omitted ...

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

You can then make updates to the single `form-field.html` template and update all of your forms, and it makes your main template a bit simpler

Comment: This works but one will have to do the same for each question in the form. I will mark it as the right answer however as it did answer the question I asked

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to create a class that does renders the HTML as you would want it. See the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format).

The example from the docs:

```
from django.forms.util import ErrorList
class DivErrorList(ErrorList):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.as_divs()
    def as_divs(self):
        if not self: return u''
        return u'<div class="errorlist">%s</div>' % ''.join([u'<div class="error">%s</div>' % e for e in self])
f = ContactForm(data, auto_id=False, error_class=DivErrorList)
f.as_p()
```